# How can I install google chrome with prefix on CentOS 7?

Tags: google-chrome, centos

I want to install google chrome on CentOS 7 but I am not admin. So is there any way to install it as a user?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8926/installing-chrome-on-linux-without-needing-to-be-root

Comment: It does not work for me!